# Pass multiple properties of a class into a function and return values of a custom attribute

Tags: c#, lambda, func

I am working on a requirement in which I need to map between two systems.
Because this mapping is rather extensive I am using a domain model with some custom attributes to do the mapping for data retrieval and crud operations.

So my domain classes look somthing like this:

```
[OhtherSystemObjectName("otherSystemAccountName")]
public class Account : SomeBaseClass
{
    [OhtherSystemAttributeName("otherSystsemAccountNameColumn")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [OhtherSystemAttributeName("otherSystsemAccountNumberColumn")]
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    [OhtherSystemAttributeName("otherSystsemAddressColumn")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [OhtherSystemAttributeName("otherSystsemPostalCodeColumn")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

}
```

I use a custom attribute to specify the column names of the other system so I do not need to bother about these when data needs to be retrieved or modified.
Now I would like to create a data retrieval method in which I can specify one or more columns using expressions. The method look somthings like this:

```
public string[] GetColumnSet<T>(Expression<Func<T, object[]>> attributes) where T : SomeBaseClass
{
    
    return ((NewArrayExpression)attributes.Body).Expressions.Select(a =>
    {

        switch (a.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
                return GetAttributeName((MemberExpression)a);
            case ExpressionType.Convert:
                return GetAttributeName((MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)a).Operand);

        }

        return null;

    }).Where(a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a)).ToArray();  
}

private static string GetAttributeName(MemberExpression memberExpression)
{
    var attribute = memberExpression.Member.GetCustomAttribute<OhtherSystemAttributeName>();
    return attribute?.AttributeName;
}
```

I use this method in my mapping layer to create a query to the other system and I need to specify the column names as an array of string. This call to this method looks something like this:

```
var colums = GetColumnSet<Account>(a => new object[] {a.Name, a.AccountNumber});
```

No I would like it to be more like this:

```
var colums = GetColumnSet<Account>(a => {a.Name, a.AccountNumber});
```

Without the `new object[]{}` but `Expression<Func<T, param object[]>>` does not compile.

Is it possible to rewrite the input expression to accomplish a syntax like this?

Comment: Have you tried something like `AutoMapper`?

Comment: @jhoefnagels With this design how would you know which name should be used for which property? What if one property does not have that attribute? What if you forgot to pass one property? etc.

Comment: @dymanoid AutoMapper is for mapping between objects, in this case we have only one object type for both systems and the attributes are populated using the mapping attributes, this works, the only thing is that we need to pass the column names if we want to query the other system without returning all columns

Comment: @Peter Csala It is ok to skip the columns without the attribute

Comment: @jhoefnagels Let's suppose you have 25 fields in your model class and only 20 fields are decorated with this particular attribute. When you call the `GetColumnSet` with that 20 field selectors then it will return a string array with 20 strings. How do you map a given string to the corresponding field?

Comment: you can easily get the attribute list from the function. Will be hard to use it with expression though

Comment: @Peter Csala, the result of the GetColumnSet is used to execute a api query. The result set of that query contains attribute names and that same custom attribute is used to map back the result set to the right attributes in my classes.

Comment: @jhoefnagels So, are you passing the field names as part of your request like OData's `expand` or `select` operator? If  so then mapping and ordering does not matter. Can you share with us the response processing part as well? So, the counterpart of the `GetColumnSet`

Comment: @Peter Csala I don't think the other source code is really relevant for this particular question

Comment: @jhoefnagels Ohh you have updated the post, but now there is a different question. Let me review it.

Comment: @jhoefnagels In C# you can't do that. With `params` you can have a call like this `GetColumnSet<Account>(a => a.Name,  a => a.AccountNumber);` if the signature of the `GetColumnSet` looks like this: `GetColumnSet<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] attributes)`

Comment: I would like to pass multiple attributes in a single expression, not an expression for each attribute which would cause a lot of repeating "a => " if you want to select a larger set of columns

Comment: @jhoefnagels Do you always need all members with the attribute or is it different from time to time? If you always need all you could omit the expression parameter...

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the exact syntax that you're after, but you could use an anonymous object:

```
var colums = GetColumnSet<Account>(a => new { a.Name, a.AccountNumber });
```

You could implement the method like this:

```
public string[] GetColumnSet<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> selector) where T : SomeBaseClass
{
    return ((NewExpression)selector.Body)
        .Type
        .GetProperties()
        .Select(prop => typeof(T)
            .GetProperty(prop.Name)?
            .GetCustomAttribute<OtherSystemAttributeName>()?
            .AttributeName)
        .Where(name => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        .ToArray();
}
```

Any property names that are specified in your anonymous object that don't exist in your `T` object, or properties that are not decorated with a `OtherSystemAttributeName` attribute are simply ignored, which seems to be the behaviour your after.

Comment: This is probably as close as it can get to what I was after

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following `Dude()` function:

```
public static void Dude(params object[] theListOfArguments) {}
```

Then the call to GetColumnSet would look only slightly different and in my opinion better than `new {...}`

```
var colums = GetColumnSet<Account>(a => Dude(a.Name, a.AccountNumber));
```

It also requires two minor changes to the GetColumnSet function.

- `Func<T,object[]>` to `Action<T>` parameter type change and
- the expression that retrieves the list of fields from the action parameters. It is the first code line in the function.

The rest of the code is the same.

```
public static string[] GetColumnSet<T>(Expression<Action<T>> attributes) where T : SomeBaseClass
{
    return ((NewArrayExpression)((MethodCallExpression)attributes.Body).Arguments.First()).Expressions.Select(a =>
    {
        switch (a.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
                return GetAttributeName((MemberExpression)a);
            case ExpressionType.Convert:
                return GetAttributeName((MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)a).Operand);
        }
        return null;
    }).Where(a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a)).ToArray();
}
```